# Can any Windows pros help me sort out this cmd promt boot failure mess?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, bootloader

i7 13700k

RTX 4070ti

32g Dominator 5200

MSI Z670 Edge

Evo 990 Pro 1TB (this replaced a 980 during this repair, to rule out disc failure; the 980 was fine it appears)

This was a month old new build that was running perfectly, until, like an idiot, I moved the PC while it was shutting down, & it became unplugged.  I hadn't set any restore points or disc images, so I couldn't use any of the Windows recovery tools to fix the issue, and from that point, it's never booted again.  Since I didn't have anything important on the build, I just wiped everything on that initial 980 Pro m.2, hoping a fresh install would solve the problem.  It did not.  That's when I suspected the 980 was corrupted, & since it was just a starter drive, that I'd planned on adding to anyway, I just went out and got a new 990, only to find that didn't help anything either.

The most obvious culprit of this failure seemed to be the boot loader, so that's where I'm at right now. I used this video for reference https://youtu.be/CZ17JrgFFhw?si=A0i6CtM8RwAhhSXD .  The relevant info in the video begins around the 10 minute mark. Problem is that I'm doing a fresh install on a new m.2 drive & some things just aren't adding up for me.

After trying to reformat the D drive, which for some reason, was where my Fat32 partition was, instead of reformatting, the file became RAW instead of FAT32? I don't seem to have an actual C drive, because that's what bios has labeled the install USB drive? My Windows files are on the E partition.  So when I tried to execute the action @13:13 to rebuild the UEFI boot loader, that's where I ended up with a RAW file for the D partition, instead of a fix. .

Are there any Windows Gods out there that can walk me thru this, before I screw things up even more?  I can't seem to find a lot of clear information about this issue, not with a clean install anyway, making me regret every wiping the 980.

Comment: Can it boot from USB, e.g., Ubuntu Live, Hiren’s BootCD PE  or other? If **not**, then the issue is at a lower level, e.g., corrupted BIOS/UEFI, hardware etc. If you *can* boot from USB, then start installation *de novo*, with an unpartitioned SSD.